How to get starting offset and ending offset of a kafka batch in Spark Streaming (Java)
In spark streaming (using Java), I am trying to print the start offset and and last offset of a specific batch taken from Kafka along with the batch related metrics (like processingStartTime, processingEndTime etc.).
Example log below

Batch Id: <someBatchId>, Beginning Offset: <someValue>, Last
Offset: <someValue>, Start Time: <processingStartTime>, End Time:
<processingEndTime>

My plan is use to use the StreamingListener and print the offsets in onBatchCompleted but later realized that this has BatchInfo which has nothing to do with the Kafka offsets.
If there was a batch id or any other unique identifier for the batch, then having different listeners (one which prints the BatchInfo and the other that prints the offsets but both the listeners would print the same batch id) would also do the trick for me. However, I can't seem to find any such connecting id anywhere.
I have put the MCVE code here - https://github.com/ravitechy/spark-kafka-tutorial/. The initializer class is https://github.com/ravitechy/spark-kafka-tutorial/blob/main/src/main/java/org/ravi/starter/StartKafkaStreaming.java
To push events to Kafka topic, I am using the kafka-console-producer.sh bundled with the Kafka installation. For now, I have only partition in the kafka topic.
Edit 1: I kind of achieved this in a very crude way.

Update the BatchOffsetsInfo with the batch id (generated), from offset and until offset in org.ravi.starter.spark.KafkaStreamInitializer#printOffsetRange
 private static void printOffsetRange(JavaDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> dataStream) {
 dataStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
     OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
     if (offsetRanges.length > 0) {
         for (OffsetRange offsetRange : offsetRanges) {
             long batchCount = offsetRange.untilOffset() - offsetRange.fromOffset();
             if (batchCount > 0) {
                 long batchId = BatchIdGenerator.INSTANCE.generateBatchId();
                 BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.setBatchId(batchId);
                 BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.setFromOffset(offsetRange.fromOffset());
                 BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.setToOffset(offsetRange.untilOffset());
                 System.out.println("Batch count : " + batchCount + ", From offset: " + offsetRange.fromOffset() + ", Until offset: " + offsetRange.untilOffset());
             }
         }
     }
 });

}

Read the BatchOffsetsInfo in the org.ravi.starter.spark.listener.BatchJobListener which is an implementation of StreamingListener
 public class BatchJobListener implements StreamingListener {

 @Override
 public void onBatchCompleted(StreamingListenerBatchCompleted batchCompleted) {
     BatchInfo batchInfo = batchCompleted.batchInfo();
     if (batchInfo.numRecords() > 0) {
         System.out.println("Batch Id: " + BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.getBatchId());
         System.out.println("Offset range: " + BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.getFromOffset() + ", " + BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.getToOffset());
         BatchOffsetsInfo.INSTANCE.reset();
     }
 }

}


Appreciate if someone could help in pointing any other better way of doing it.
